# Where can I save plugin data?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I created a plugin which has a shortcode that displays a button in a form. I would like to track the button clicks with an onclick() script and save the amount of clicks to a meta field. I am just not sure where to save this data. I don't want this data to be saved to a posts meta field, as this isn't post specific. Should such data be saved to the wp-options table? What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the amount of details you want to save, you could also create a table for it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I only need to save 2 pieces of data so I think wp-options should suffice. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not post specific then it should be saved as an option in `wp_options` with `add_option()` or `update_option()`.

Comment: Thank you. Would there be anything unsafe about displaying the info I want to save on the frontend?

Comment: Not if you properly sanitize and escape it. But that also applies to post meta.